# Determine connectivity of data and separate into groups

Tags: r

I have a simple question on grouping data. Take the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,5,5),c(2,3,4,7,6))
colnames(df)<- c("A","B")
df
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 5 7
5 5 6
```

What I want to do is output something (table, list, vector, etc) created by collapsing the original data frame based on connections between elements, so the ideal output would be:

```
1 2 3 4 
5 7 6
```

I am open to any suggestions for the best way to handle this types of data.

Edit:
To clarify how I got the output:
Row names are ignored.
1 is in the same row as 2 making a set: (1,2)
2 is in the same row as 3, so 3 joins the set: (1,2,3)
4 is in the same row as 3, so 4 joins the set: (1,2,3,4)
5 is in the same row as 7 and neither of these are in existing set so new set:  (5,7)
5 is in the same row as 6 so 6 is added to the set: (5,7,6)

Comment: How did you get the output?

Comment: That is the desired output

Comment: @RonakShah is asking about the rules to connect elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a network graph of the data with the *igraph* package.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(df)
plot(g)
```

From the plot we can see the components of the graph of `g` and how they relate to each other.

[image]

I don't use this package very often, but it seems like the way to get the components is to use `get.vertex.attribute()`, as shown below.

```
lapply(decompose.graph(g), get.vertex.attribute, "name")
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "5" "7" "6"
```

Comment: Hmm I think this could work but I am getting an error

cmp <- components(graph.data.frame(df))$membership
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  as.sociomatrix.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, network, or list.

Comment: I think this really close though because the graph displays and this is the correct split of the elements so its just a matter of accessing the networks.

Comment: still no go.  "Error in decompose(g) : time series has no or less than 2 periods"

Comment: ah got it, you were missing a bit from the decompose. This works:    
`lapply(decompose.graph(g), function(x) as.numeric(colnames(x[])))` 

Thanks so much!